# Jquery DatePicker set to not auto-open

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
<div id="newSwitchDialog">
        <span id="name"></span><br /><br />
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Effective Date: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="startDate" /><br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>End Date: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" id="endDate" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

When I open this dialog via a click event:

```
$('#yup').live('click', function () {
            $('#name').text($('#selectedSponsorName').text());
            $("#newSwitchDialog").dialog('open');
        });
```

The datepicker automatically pops open for the first input. How do I make it not do that? Only option I found was to set it to open on a button click, but I couldn't find any `autoOpen` sort of thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try setting the `tabindex` attribute on the fields containing the datepicker widget to `-1`:

```
<input type="text" id="startDate" tabindex="-1" />
```

(same for `endDate`)

**Before:** http://jsfiddle.net/NzfwD/

**After:** http://jsfiddle.net/pyJUR/